# How do I dynamically choose which fetch to target in this loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch, fetch-api

The function below will fetch a list of items, I would then like to store the data without duplicates in its own array

```
async function fetchAtt() {
    let seturl = `https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/templates?collection_name=mlb.topps&schema_name=promo&has_assets=true&page=1&limit=3414&order=desc&sort=created
    `;
    
    try {
        let res = await fetch(seturl);
        console.log(res);
        return await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

[image]

It will then return a list of unique items, I would then like to create a function that loops through the data, and stores data from "immutable_data" such as img, name, legal, artist, rarity, variant.

[image]

---

I have managed to create this function that will store all the unique names in an array and then console logs it but I need to create a function that allows me to pass in param and then use that param as the target inside of immutable_data

```
async function renderTags() {
    let atts = await fetchAtt();
    var flags = [], output = [], l = atts.data.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( flags[atts.data[i].immutable_data.variant]) continue;
        flags[atts.data[i].immutable_data.variant] = true;
        output.push(atts.data[i].immutable_data.variant);
    }
    console.log(output);
}

renderTags();
```

[image]

as you can see above it's working perfectly if I manually change `atts.data[i].immutable_data.variant` to `atts.data[i].immutable_data.rarity`

What would be the best way to build a function where I can pass in an arg and use that arg after `immutable_data`.

for example `atts.data[i].immutable_data.name`

Comment: Your `seturl` string has a trailing line-break in it, is that intentional?

Comment: Side-note: you can simplify your code with `for(of)` instead of `for( i = 0`.

Comment: While `flags` is initialized as an array, yes - but your script is using it like an `object` (because you're using `string` keys, arrays use `number` keys).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract values.
- [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a `Set` to get only distinct values. (Then use `Set.prototype.values()` to get the distinct values back out, though note the `values()` does not return a "real" `Array`)

  - While using `Array.prototype.filter` with an inner-call to `Array.prototype.indexOf` will also work, it will have awful runtime performance (`O(n*m)`) whereas `reduce` with a `Set` is `O(n)` which is far, far better.

### Part 1: Extract values:

```
async function renderTags() {

    const atts = await fetchAtt();

    if( !Array.isArray( atts.data ) )
    {
        throw new Error( "atts.data is not an array." );
    }
    
    const artists  = atts.data.map( d => d.immutable_data.artist );
    const rarities = atts.data.map( d => d.immutable_data.rarity );
    const variants = atts.data.map( d => d.immutable_data.variant );
    
    console.log( artists );
    console.log( rarities ); // [ "Legendary", "Epic", "Epic", "Super Rare", "Common" ]
    console.log( variants ); // [ "Gold", "Silver", "Silver", "Bronze", "Wood" ]
}
```

### Part 2: Extract distinct values:

```
async function renderTags() {

    const atts = await fetchAtt();

    if( !Array.isArray( atts.data ) )
    {
        throw new Error( "atts.data is not an array." );
    }
    
    const artists  = atts.data.map( d => d.immutable_data.artist ).reduce( ( set, e ) => set.set( e ), new Set() ).values();
    const rarities = atts.data.map( d => d.immutable_data.rarity ).reduce( ( set, e ) => set.set( e ), new Set() ).values();
    const variants = atts.data.map( d => d.immutable_data.variant ).reduce( ( set, e ) => set.set( e ), new Set() ).values();
    
    console.log( artists );
    console.log( rarities ); // [ "Legendary", "Epic", "Super Rare", "Common" ]
    console.log( variants ); // [ "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze", "Wood" ]
}
```

### Part 3: Make it a single reusable function:

- Simplify the inline functions by extracting `immutable_data` objects in an initial first-pass.
- Add `Array.from()` to return a "real" `Array`, and `sort` it for good measure.

```
function map_distinct( array, getter ) {

    const values   = array.map( getter );
    const distinct = values.reduce( ( set, e ) => set.set( e ), new Set() ).values();
    const asArray  = Array.from( distinct );
    asArray.sort(); 

    return asArray;
}

async function renderTags() {

    const atts = await fetchAtt();

    if( !Array.isArray( atts.data ) )
    {
        throw new Error( "atts.data is not an array." );
    }

    const imms = atts.data.map( d => d.immutable_data );
    
    const artists  = map_distinct( imms, d => d.artist );
    const rarities = map_distinct( imms, d => d.rarity );
    const variants = map_distinct( imms, d => d.variant );
    
    console.log( artists );
    console.log( rarities ); // [ "Common", "Epic", "Legendary", "Super Rare" ]
    console.log( variants ); // [ "Bronze", "Gold", "Silver", "Wood" ]
}
```